# report viewer (2010) subreport

Tags: c#, entity-framework, rdlc, report-viewer2010

I'm getting the error below once in a while (not at all times):

> The subreport 'Header' could not be found at the specified location \
>   ...\Header.rdlc. Please verify that the subreport has been published
>   and that the name is correct

All my rdlc files are located at the network drive.

I already checked if there was a network problem at the time of the generation, but found nothing.

I have 3 different sub reports on the main report. No issue with two sub reports. issue is only with one sub report. And the structure is same for all 3 sub reports.

I'm pretty sure there is nothing wrong with the data/parameter, because when I tried to execute the report again, it generates properly. It happens 1 in 100 reports, and it is bugging me. And when I saw this issue, observed that the time taken to generate the report is 10 minutes.

Im using EF, C# + RDLC (EF object as dataset).